# Android: Performing periodic tasks when activity is in the foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to perform some periodic tasks as long as an **activity is in the foreground only** (I do not need any processing when the app is asleep). There seem to be two options

1. [Intent Service with Alarm Manager / PendingIntent / BroadcastReceiver](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services)
2. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Please provide typical scenarios when either of these should be used, and  pros/cons if any.

Comment: I do not understand how any one of these options has anything to do with an `Activity` being in the foreground. Have you ever considered just using the `onResume()` and `onPause()` callbacks to start and stop your work?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes but what is started or stopped in onResume or onPause if not a non-UI thread ? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: @XaverKapeller The reason the question is here, is because (a) I'm requesting a pros and cons analysis, not an opinion (hence the "and why?" part in the question) (b) over time the Android API has evolved and there are many choices to achieve the same objective, and the newer options supercede the older ones - I want to know the "currently accepted best practice".

Comment: @user90766 And if you follow the link I posted in my previous comment ([**this one**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354)) then you will see that best practice questions are not on topic or wanted on Stack Overflow. As I said before this is literally what the "primarily opinion-based" close reason is for. The thing is there is never just one way to do something. Different programmers are going to have different preferences on do things in different ways. And this doesn't make one way better than the other.

Comment: And there is no one right way do to something.

Comment: @XaverKapeller this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on whether you want to couple this background process with a specific Activity. `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is technically just a ExecutorService with schedule. It is or should be coupled with Activity lifecycle (e.g stop on onPause, start in onStart). Service is not. It can keep running outside the Activity or even Application scope. Any Activity can communicate with it through `ResultReceiver`.

Comment: So a Service might have more overhead than the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, because it has its own process?

Comment: Not really. Both spawn threads and each thread is what I interpret as process. In fact ThreadPoolExecutor is supposed to run as many threads as there are in the pool size. So this finally depends on your needs. If your process cannot be bounded by Activity like alarm, file download or music streaming then definitely use Service.

Answer (score 3):

Handler is way simpler and more efficient when dealing with this.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   Handler taskHandler;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInsantsState);
      taskHandler = new Handler();
   }

   @Override
   public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      taskHandler.postDelatyed(new TaskRunnable(), 50000);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
      super.stop();
      taskHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
   }

   private class TaskRunnable implements Runnable {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           Log.d("Home", "Heeeyyyyyy I'm typing something!");
           taskHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
       }
   }
}
```

If you need a background thread running then you can use HandlerThread.

```
TaskHandlerThread taskThread

// TaskHandler is created in the TaskHandler class instead

public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   taskThread = new HandlerThread("TaskHandler");
}

public void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

   taskHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
   taskThread.quitSafely();
}

public class TaskHandlerThread extends HandlerThread { 
   @Override
   void onLooperPrepared() {
       taskHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
       taskHandler.post(new TaskRunnable());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use timer task start timer in onStart() and stop it in onStop()

look at this example

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimerFixed = new CountDownTimer(Time, Tick) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
// this will call every second 
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// this will call when timer is go to finish 
        this.start();

    }
};
```

if you need periodic tasks for every 10 mins, pass 10 mins and tick time to countdowntimer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use light weight single background thread for the same.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {

            //put you code here

            sleep(1000);

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};

thread.start();
```

after that when activity goes in background some thing like in onStop() method stop this thread using,`thread.stop();`

And if you are going to perform UI related changes then us runOnUiThread. Because you can not perform UI related change from background thread.